# Broadcast message only for the owner of the models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I am building an application where users can create event and other users can "join" and add comments to events, also they can open a chat between them, I have a model named "Notification" where I want to store all the notifications in the system and I want to warn to the owner of the event whenever a user comment on his events, write a new message to him, etc.

This is the part of code for comments that I have wrote:

Notification Model:

```
/* Notification.js */
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    title: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    text: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    type:{
        type: 'string',
        enum: ['new_assistant', 'cancel_assistant', 'new_message', 'new_comment'],
        required: 'true'
    },
    read: {
        type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },
    user: {
        model: 'user'
    }
  }
};
```

This is where I subscribe the socket to his notification model:

```
Notification.find({
  user: owner_id
}).then(function(notifications) {
  return Notification.watch(req.socket);
});
```

And whenever a user comment in an event I create a new Notification record:

```
Notification.create({
  title: 'A new user has comment',
  text: "Hola",
  type: 'new_comment',
  read: false,
  user: event.owner
}).then(function(comment) {
  return Notification.publishCreate({
    id: notification.id,
    title: 'A new user has comment'
  });
});
```

That code run but this sent a socket message to all users and I just want to warn to the owner of the event (And in the future to the users who going to this event).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

watch sends the model instance creation message to all of the sockets that are watching the model, the same registration could have been performed without finding the notification as it's not instance dependent, i.e. just call: `Notification.watch(req.socket);`

To send the notification to a single subscriber use [sails.sockets](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets)

Create a room for the owner when you want to subscribe:

```
sails.sockets.join(req.socket, owner_id);
```

And when you want to publish broadcast to this room:

```
Notification.create({
  title: 'A new user has comment',
  text: "Hola",
  type: 'new_comment',
  read: false,
  user: event.owner
}).then(function(comment) {
  sails.sockets.broadcast(event.owner, {
    id: notification.id,
    title: 'A new user has comment'
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi. I implemented your code and It works. Thank you!